# Trying to get drawable resource ID from its name in Android

Tags: android, android-xml, android-resources, android-drawable

I have a resource file like this:

**strings.xml**

```
<string name="category01">My Category 01</string>
<string name="category02">My Category 02</string>
<string name="category03">My Category 03</string>

<string-array name="array_category_01">
    <item name="title">@string/category01</item>
    <item name="image">@drawable/img01</item>
</string-array>

<string-array name="array_category_02">
    <item name="title">@string/category02</item>
    <item name="image">@drawable/img02</item>
</string-array>

<string-array name="array_category_03">
    <item name="title">@string/category03</item>
    <item name="image">@drawable/img03</item>
</string-array>

<string-array name="categories_array">
    <item>@array/array_category_01</item>
    <item>@array/array_category_02</item>
    <item>@array/array_category_03</item>
</string-array>
```

**Note**: @drawable/img01, @drawable/img02 and @drawable/img03 are png images locates at res\drawable folder

Later I perform below iteration to retrieve category-images pairs:

```
    Resources res = this.context.getResources();
    TypedArray ta = res.obtainTypedArray(R.array.categories_array);
    int n = ta.length();
    String[][] array = new String[n][];
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        int id = ta.getResourceId(i, 0);
        if (id > 0) {
            array[i] = res.getStringArray(id);
        } else {
            // something wrong with the XML
        }
    }
    ta.recycle();
```

so for example at the end I get an array which contents are:

```
array[0]
  |
  ---> [0] "My Category 01"
  |
  ---> [1] "res/drawable-xxhdpi-v4/img01.png"

array[1]
  |
  ---> [0] "My Category 02"
  |
  ---> [1] "res/drawable-xxhdpi-v4/img02.png"

array[2]
  |
  ---> [0] "My Category 03"
  |
  ---> [1] "res/drawable-xxhdpi-v4/img03.png"
```

It is just what I am expected to get, no problem until here.

Later in my code, I need to get the resource ID of one of the categories contained in the above array in order for set the content of an ImageView object so I perform below (let's say I want the image for category 2):

```
ImageView imageView = (ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.categoryicon);

int resID = this.context.getResources().getIdentifier(array[1][1] , "drawable", this.context.getPackageName());
imageView.setImageResource(resID);
```

My problem is that resID is zero so it means drawable resource has not been found...

In order to work I need image names in the **array** to be img01, img02, img03 instead of "res/drawable-xxhdpi-v4/img01.png", "res/drawable-xxhdpi-v4/img02.png" and "res/drawable-xxhdpi-v4/img03.png" respectively so when I pass the names to getIdentifier through array[x][y] it works.

How can I get rid of this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One simple solution would be to parse the string and get only the image name as below.

```
String[] Image1 = array[1][1].split("/");
String s = Image1[Image1.length-1].replace(".png","").trim();

int resID = this.context.getResources().getIdentifier(s , "drawable", this.context.getPackageName());
```

Comment: Great! thanks! Also this works: String imgName = array[0][1]; imgName.substring(imgName.lastindexof("/") + 1, imgName.lastindexof("."));

Answer (score 1):

array[1][1] is the path to the resource. You must specify a name.See http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources.html#getIdentifier%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29